# Why it's going in else part even after satisfying the if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

I've following HTML code of a form:

```
<form name="question_issue_form" id="question_issue_form" action="question_issue.php">
          <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
            <tbody>    
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question is wrong" id ="chkQueWrong">Question is wrong</input>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Answers are wrong" id ="chkAnsWrong">Answers are wrong</input></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question direction is incorrect" id ="chkDirIncorrect">Question direction is incorrecct</input></td>                
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Other" id ="chkOther">Other</input></td>          
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="set_message" style="display:none;"><textarea name="que_issue_comment" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="100"></textarea></td>      
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="report_question_issue"/></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
```

I want to validate the form before submitting the form such that at least one checkbox is checked from all the above checkboxes and when checkbox with value "Other" is checked then the text area shouldn't be blank. For it I've tried following code, but it's showing alert even after selecting one or more checkboxes. Also the text area validation is also not properly working. Can anyone please help me in correcting this validation code before submission of form? If a single error is thrown the form should not get submit. Following is the jQUery code I 've tried.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#chkOther').click(function () {
      $('.set_message').toggle(this.checked);
  });

  //This function is use for edit transaction status
  $(document).on('click', '#report_question_issue', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      //$.colorbox.close();

      //for confirmation that status change
      var ans = confirm("Are you sure to report the question issue over?");
      if (!ans) { //alert("Yes its false");
          return false;
      }

      var post_url = $('#post_url').val();

      var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("que_issue[]");

      var checkedAtLeastOne = false;

      $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) { alert("In If");
              //atleast one is checked
              checkedAtLeastOne = true;
          } else { alert("In Else");
              //error
              alert("Check at least one checkbox");
          }

          var other = document.getElementById("chkOther");
          var textfield = document.getElementByName("que_issue_comment");
          if ($(other).is(":checked")) {
              if ($(textfield).val().length == 0) {
                  //error
                  alert("Fill in the textarea");
              }
          }
      });

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: post_url,
          data: $('#question_issue_form').serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
              alert("The values have been inserted");
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Seriously, you are asking each ten minutes a completly different question. Tell your boss to hire some developers...

Comment: @A.Wolff:Please don't misunderstand me but I'm having some serious deadline and no one is here to help me so I'm asking for a helping hand froma pool of experts.

Comment: "no one is here to help me" You have some accurate answers most of the time. Please don't misunderstand us but we are not here to do your job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is checking for each checkbox in your page. That's why it going to else part and alerting `Check at least one checkbox` .To avoid that Try the following code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chkOther').click(function() {
        $('.set_message').toggle(this.checked);
    });
    //This function is use for edit transaction status
    $(document).on('click', '#report_question_issue', function(e) {
        var submit = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        //$.colorbox.close();
        //for confirmation that status change
        var ans = confirm("Are you sure to report the question issue over?");
        if (!ans) { //alert("Yes its false");
            submit = false;
        }
        var post_url = $('#post_url').val();
        var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("que_issue[]");
        var checkedAtLeastOne = false;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                checkedAtLeastOne = true;
                return false; //to break from each()
            }
        });
        if (checkedAtLeastOne) {
            //alert("In If");
            var other = $("#chkOther");
            var textfield = $("[name=que_issue_comment]");
            if (other.is(":checked")) {
                if ($.trim($(textfield).val()).length == 0) {
                    //error
                    alert("Fill in the textarea");
                    submit = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Check at least one checkbox");
            submit = false;
        }
        if (submit) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: post_url,
                data: $('#question_issue_form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("The values have been inserted");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Fix the error");
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/VqmzL/18)</kbd>

Comment: :Your logic for at least one checkbox worked perfectly but the logic for textarea when checkbox with value "Other" is checked is still not working.

Comment: One small issue is still there. The form is getting submitted even after the errors come. How to resolve that one?

Comment: The form is not getting submitted even after filling the textarea. The alert is coming saying "Fill in the textarea". I've added the code to updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/VqmzL/11/

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement is executed multiple times, once for each checkbox. You'll see the alert for every checkbox that isn't checked, even if another checkbox has been checked. You need to completely change the logic; iterate through them all looking for a checked checkbox, and stop the iteration as soon as you find one.

Then, after examining them all, determine whether or not the alert needs to be displayed.